# How to install node.js "monitor" package

Tags: node.js, npm, monitor

I want to install the following node.js dashboard package but the instructions are confusing.
I followed the instructions at the bottom of this link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/monitor

...I used these two commands:

```
npm install monitor-dashboard
npm start monitor-dashboard
```

However, there are no instructions as to what is suppose to go into the start script. My application entry is `app.js`

Also, I am unclear if I need to install the `monitor` package before `monitor-dashboard` or if the `monitor-dashboard` package has everything I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggested action:**

Try running `node node_modules/monitor-dashboard/monitor.js` in your terminal from the directory that contains your `node_modules`.

**Explanation:**

The instructions at http://lorenwest.github.io/monitor-dashboard/ say to run the following code:

```
$ npm install monitor-dashboard
$ npm start monitor-dashboard
```

I believe what it wants to happen is to run the `npm start` command for the `monitor-dashboard` dependency we installed. However, your project's `package.json` doesn't know HOW to run that `start monitor-dashboard` command.

So, I did a little digging and found that the `package.json` for `monitor-dashboard` wants to run `node monitor.js`. Instead of asking `monitor-dashboard` to run that command, we're just doing it manually from the root directory of our project.

Comment: Thanks got it. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the package you need to include the Monitor package first within your application by running: `npm install monitor` and then include the package into your application:  `require('monitor').start();` this will allow the Monitor Dashboard to display your monitoring efforts.

You can then install the monitor package as you have outlined in your question.

```
npm install monitor-dashboard
npm start monitor-dashboard
```

This will then output all your monitors into the dashboard view.

Comment: It doesn't work when I run npm start monitor-dashboard in a new terminal.

Comment: I am pretty sure with Express JS you need to include it as follows: `app.use(require('monitor')());` - I am a little rusty with Express.

Comment: that crashed my server

Comment: When I do it with "require('monitor').start(); " I get the error:      "missing script: start"

Comment: Ok what about: `var monitor = require('monitor').start();` or `const monitor = require('monitor').start();` - yeah your error is coming from the fact that `.start();` has not been initialised.

Comment: If I create a completly new server.js file that is independent of my app.js file then THAT file launches, but when I try to place "require('monitor').start()" inside of it , the page just idles. No dashboard appears at http://localhost:4200/ as the instruction say

Comment: The question was answered but I appreciate it.